# Gradient derived from Jacobian?

Tags: calculus, nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent, jacobian

I was reading this wikipedia page on [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) (section: Solution of non-linear system) when I came across this formula:

$\nabla F(\mathbf {x} ^{(0)})=J_{G}(\mathbf {x} ^{(0)})^{\mathrm {T} }G(\mathbf {x} ^{(0)})$

How did this equation come about? Sorry for my shaky calculus if this sounds stupid, but this is the only point in this section that I don't understand.

Comment: It would help to mention in the body of the question that $F(x) = (1/2) G(x)^T G(x)$.

Comment: related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818147/jacobian-and-gradient-relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the article

$$
F({\bf x}) = \frac{1}{2}G^T({\bf x}) G({\bf x}) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_j G_j({\bf x}) G_j({\bf x}) \tag{1}
$$

Take the derivative w.r.t to $x_i$

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i} &=& 
\frac{1}{2}\sum_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left[G_j({\bf x}) G_j({\bf x}) \right]  = \sum_j  \color{blue}{\frac{\partial G_j({\bf x})}{\partial x_i}} G_j({\bf x}) \\
&=& \sum_j \color{blue}{[J_G({\bf x})]_{ij}} G_j({\bf x}) = [J_{G}({\bf x}) G({\bf x})]_i \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

where the $(i,j)$-th component of matrix $J_G$ is defined as

$$
[J_G({\bf x})]_{ij} = \frac{\partial G_j({\bf x})}{\partial x_i} \tag{3}
$$

Eq. (2) tells you what the $i$-th component of the gradient is, if you put them all together you get

$$
\nabla F({\bf x}) = J_G({\bf x}) G({\bf x}) \tag{4}
$$